# Trying to understand stacking defense bonuses from Racial / Feat / Items in DND4e?

Tags: dnd-4e, magic-items, feats, defense, racial-traits

I am a relatively new player to DND (4e). I've tried to look this information up and have found tidbits but I am still unclear. This is a multi-part question though the core of it is understanding if there are certain "types" of bonuses that are considered the same but may be labeled something different (e.g., racial vs feat - do they stack or are they considered the same for stacking purposes?) and how far do the bonuses go when stacking?

**(Minotaur Warden)**

*Part 1:*

**Heedless Charge (Racial): +2 AC against Opp Attacks while charging.**

**Heavy Blade Expertise (Feat): +2 all defenses against Opp Attacks.**

- If I charge and get hit by an Opportunity Attack, does that give me a +4 AC and +2 Fort/Will/Reflex or just a +2 all defenses since Racial and Feat [are?] considered the same (or for some other reason?)

*Part 2:*

**Tusk Shield (Light Shield): Whenever you charge, you gain a +2 item bonus to all defenses until the start of your next turn.**

- If I charge (regardless of what the outcome of the defense bonus is in part 1), does this shield allow for the item bonus to apply to opportunity attacks that I may encounter as part of that charge? Technically an Opportunity Attack is an immediate interrupt (I believe) but at the same time the charge will still occur unless the character dies. The shield doesn't specify that the charge has to be successful, just that you take the action (Listed as "Properties" for the shield, not an effect or hit).
- If this bonus DOES apply to Opportunity Attacks, I assume it would stack with whatever the outcome of Part 1 is since its from an item source?

Comment: keep in mind that just because a bonus is granted by a feat or racial ability, it may not be a "feat bonus" for instance the defense bonus from the heavy blade expertise against opportunity attacks is untyped so it will stack with anything.

Comment: Ahhh, that does clear it up a bit, thanks! Does that make the bonus from Heedless Charge also untyped?

Comment: No. If you read the description it indicates it's a racial bonus.

Comment: You're right, it does! However, it doesn't print out from the Wizards character builder with that specification. Thanks again ;)

Answer (score 6):

## Bonuses of Different Types Stack

So Racial and Feat and Item bonuses all stack with one another. Thus, in the first case, you do get +4 to AC, as well as +2 to Fort/Ref/Will. And in the second case, yes, the bonus does stack with the Tusk Shield.

As for the Tusk Shield, yes, it means for Opportunity Attacks. As long as you are in the process of charging, the bonus applies. Opportunity Attacks are, in fact, the primary thing that the bonus defends against.